# Is there any way to get older seasonal achievements?

Tags: killing-floor

Was looking to get other skins for Killing Floor, but it seems that I need to have participated in the seasonal events to have received them.

Is there any way to get these skins without having to wait a full half-year/year just to get those achievements?

Comment: Just a guess: no http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2386339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title:
Yes you can get the older seasonal achievements.
I got the 2010 Christmas achievement in the year 2012:
[image: steam achievement]

As for your question in the body, there is no way to get the seasonal achievements (Halloween and Christmas) until their respective seasons.  You're going to have to wait the "full half-year/year"

Comment: Any way without waiting? Can I use Steam Achievement Manager or anything of the sort without breaking VAC?

Comment: @Retrosaur Unfortunately no, there is no way without breaking VAC.  During the Halloween and Christmas times the Tripwire team changes the settings and posts in the 'news' section, and thats how they spawn the special mutants and open the achievements